# How to drop all tables under a username which were created before a date?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to drop all table that were created before jan 1st 2010. I have came across some example here at stackoverflow but none meets my need.There is no conflict with primary key which is a good point. It has to be in pl/sql but sql is ok, I can figure it out.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  You talk about dropping tables, but then you mention "There is no conflict with primary key" which isn't a consideration for dropping tables.  Did you mean deleting records from a table?  Did you mean "there are no foreign keys"?  What examples did you try, and why didn't they work?

Comment: yes there is no foreign key

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`DBA_OBJECTS`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-4EB0E78C-EA23-4D7B-98F2-D0583C7C1F62.htm) to find all the tables created before a particular date and use it to create a string like  `DROP TABLE <TABLE_NAME>`. Then you can use [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317) to drop the table.

```
DECLARE
  V_STRING VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN

  FOR I IN (SELECT *
              FROM SYS.DBA_OBJECTS T
             WHERE T.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
               AND T.OWNER = 'USERNAME'
               AND T.CREATED < date '2010-01-01') LOOP

    V_STRING := 'DROP TABLE ' || I.OBJECT_NAME;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_STRING;

  END LOOP;

END;
```

If you only want to drop tables for your own user then [`USER_OBJECTS`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-6EEE5C20-C731-406B-B772-865B400D349A.htm) only contains objects owned by the user you are logged in as.

Comment: good answer.. the only thing I'd add would be the date mask to avoid implicit date  conversions(something like AND T.CREATED<TO_DATE('01-JAN-2010','DD-MON-YYYY'), wich may cause  problems with database with oter date formats

Comment: Hi. I've removed the implicit date to string conversion by using a [date literal](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-6EEE5C20-C731-406B-B772-865B400D349A.htm) and added some links to improve your answer. Also, you don't need the semi-colon at the end of the string you're going to execute